# Strcpy Violacion de Core sin sentido

Tags: c

queria solicitar ayuda urgente ya que estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito encontrar done tengo mi error

mi programa se supone hace un scrap a un texto y evalua si hay palabras que apoyen o ataquen a un candidato (trabajo de escuela)

Mi problema es que cuando meto las palabras a evaluar en una tabla hash por medio de strcpy ejecuta todo mi codigo pero me muestra hasta el final violacion de core generado.

Me estoy volviendo loco

Copio mi codigo

```
  void leerArchivo(Nodo *T, char *dato){
FILE *fpl=0;
fpl= fopen(dato, "r");
char linea[20];
unsigned y;
while (fgets(linea, 20, fpl)){
    fscanf(fpl, "%s", &linea);
    y=H(linea, 300);
    i=0;
    while(T[y % 300].status==1 && i<301){
        y=y+i;
        i++;
    }
    y=y%300;
    T[y].status=1;
    strcpy(T[y].palabra, linea);
    //printf("%s\n",T[y].palabra);
}       
fclose(fpl);
return;
}
```

en  otro documento llamo mi codigo y pongo lo siguiente

```
 void leerDoc(Nodo *T,char *dato, nombres *estos){
FILE *fplc=0;
fplc= fopen(dato, "r");
char linea[500];
unsigned y;
while (!feof(fplc)){
    fscanf(fplc, " %s ", &linea);
    y=H(linea, 300);
    for (i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(strcmp(estos[i].nombreCan,linea)==0 ){
            printf("encontre un candidato: %s\n", linea);           
        }
    }
        if(strcmp(T[y].palabra, linea)==0){
        printf("encontre una palabra: %s\n", linea);
    }
}       
fclose(fplc);
return;}

//||strcmp(estos[i].nombreCan,linea)==0
//strcmp(T[i].palabra,linea)==0 ||

int main(){
Nodo *T;
T=initHash();
leerArchivo(&T,"palabras.txt");
nombres *estos;
estos=IniCan();
BuscarCandidatos(&estos, "nombres.txt");
leerDoc(&T,"html2", &estos);
printf("esto deberia salir\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué es `T` exactamente? ¿Una lista enlazada? ¿Una array? Y, si es un array, ¿De qué tamaño? ¿Cómo has reservado la memoria?

Comment: T es un array que ocupo para llenar mi tabla hash
tiene tamaño de 300 Nodos
un nodo es un elemento con un atributo char palabra[20], y un int status.
hago un apuntador de tipo nodo y le asigno con malloc el tamaño de los 300 nodos, regreso este apuntador y lo asigno a T

Comment: Esa información tienes que ponerla en la pregunta... edita la misma, por favor. Si obligas a la gente a tener que leerse los comentarios para entender la pregunta vas a recibir muchas menos respuestas